# Icons always show larger

Tags: android, graphics, icons

How come my icons (both on the action bar and in an ImageView) show larger than the actual thing on disk? Even an 48*48 icon on a tab in the action bar get scaled up to something larger that looks pixelated.

Comment: What drawable density folder (e.g. drawable-mdpi) are you using for these assets, and what is the density bucket for the device are you using?

Comment: Please refer to this page: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion you are placing the icons in drawable folder.When you would try to run it on a higher density the system will scale up your assets. Please ensure that you are placing the assets in the right drawable folder

Comment: Thanks, your answer's the closest to the solution :-) It took me a while to figure out I have a hdpi phone :-)

Answer (score 0):

The relevant Android documentation on [supporting multiple screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#support) explains not only what is happening but how to avoid it:

> **Provide different bitmap drawables for different screen densities**
>   By default, Android scales your bitmap drawables (.png, .jpg, and .gif files) and Nine-Patch drawables (.9.png files) so that they render at the appropriate physical size on each device. For example, if your application provides bitmap drawables only for the baseline, medium screen density (mdpi), then the system scales them up when on a high-density screen, and scales them down when on a low-density screen. This scaling can cause artifacts in the bitmaps. To ensure your bitmaps look their best, you should include alternative versions at different resolutions for different screen densities.
>   The configuration qualifiers you can use for density-specific resources are ldpi (low), mdpi (medium), hdpi (high), and xhdpi (extra high). For example, bitmaps for high-density screens should go in drawable-hdpi/.